# Regex for astronomical declination (latitude) on +/-90 degrees boundary in hhmmss

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to ensure a Regex matching pattern works well for all astronomical declinations between -90 and +90 degrees.

I'm using a matching pattern as follows:

```
^(?:(?:[+-]?([0-8]?\d|2[0-9])[°:\s])\s?\s?([0-5]?\d)[\':\s]?)\s?([0-5]?\d).?([0-9]?\d{1,9})[\"]?$
```

I have added some strings that I wish to fail and succeed here:

https://regex101.com/r/Z0Kf6I/1

I have almost got it, but I'm struggling how to allow for the following strings which I want to be matched but are currently not:

```
90°00'00.00" => Succeed, but failing
90:00:00.00 => Succeed, but failing
+90:00:00.00 => Succeed, but failing
-90:00:00.00 => Succeed, but failing
+90°00'00.00" => Succeed, but failing
-90°00'00.00" => Succeed, but failing
90 0 0.00 => Succeed, but failing
```

Essentially, this is because I have a match for a single character present in the list below `[0-8]`. But changing this to `[0-9]` will obviously then allow values greater than 90, e.g., 91,92, etc but these should fail.

Any pro Regex tips on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

It looks like I can get a little closer with this regex:

```
^(?:(?:[+-]?([0-8]?\d|90)[°:\s])\s?([0-5]?\d)[\':\s]?)\s?([0-5]?\d)\.(\d{1,9})[\"]?
```

Comment: Are you dead set on regex?

Comment: Not particularly ... I would like a low level no-dependency solution ...

Comment: Why do you want to fail with no milliseconds?

Comment: What language BTW?

Comment: Some of this doesn't make sense, like the capturing group `([0-8]?\d|2[0-9])`. Why is the literal 2 in the alternative? For that matter, why is the alternative there at all? `2[0-9]` will be matched by `[0-8]?\d`.

Comment: But really my suggestion would be that a regular expression is not a program, and what you're needing to do seems to require some logic. What language/tool are you using to do this processing? I guarantee there is a better way to do this that is going to be easier to work with in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt:

```js
^[+-]?(90(?!.*[1-9])|[0-8]?[0-9]?)(?:°|:|\s)\s*(60(?!.*[1-9])|[0-5]?[0-9])(?:\'|:|\s)\s*([0-5]?[0-9]\.\d+)(?:\")?$
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/A2PLer/1)

It would also not match minutes bigger than `60` like

89° 60' 59.99" => additional Fail case

89° 60' 60.00" => additional Fail case

89° 59' 60.01" => additional Fail case

Answer (score 2):

I'd treat the case where it's exactly 90 separately, like so:

```
^[+-]?(?:[0-8]\d|\d)[°: ]?\s*?\d\d?[': ]\s*?\d\d?\.\d+\"?|^[+-]?90[°: ]\s*?00?[': ]\s*?00?\.0+\"?
```

https://regex101.com/r/wByk9t/1

Comment: Yeh that's good, but it doesn't have the matching groups unfortunately ...

Comment: Here it is with groups: https://regex101.com/r/CkyzDh/1

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid interpreting numbers in regex, not necessarily because it's impossible, but because it's harder to read and maintain. You can match with the following regex:

```
([+-]?\d+)([°: ])(\d+)([': ])(\d+[.]\d*)("?)
```

Now you can just convert groups 1, 3, 5 into a number and check if it is > 90. You can also check if the separators in groups 2, 4, 6 are matching or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^[+-]?([0-8]?\d|90(?=(?:\D*0)*\D*$))[°:\s]\s{0,2}([0-5]?\d)[':\s]?\s?([0-5]?\d).?(\d{1,10})\"?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z0Kf6I/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[+-]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
- `([0-8]?\d|90(?=(?:\D*0)*\D*$))` - Group 1: an optional digit from `0` to `8` and then any one digit, or `90` that is immediately followed with zero or more repetitions of any non-digit char followed with a `0` char, and then any non-digit chars till end of string
- `[°:\s]` - `°`, `:` or a whitespace
- `\s{0,2}` - zero, one or two whitespaces
- `([0-5]?\d)` - Group 2: an optional digit from `0` to `5` range and then one digit
- `[':\s]?` - an optional `'`, `:` and whitespace
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `([0-5]?\d)` - Group 3: an optional digit from `0` to `5` range and then one digit
- `.?` - any optional char other than line break chars
- `(\d{1,10})` - Group 4: one to ten digits
- `\"?` - an optional `"` char.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that 90 is the maximum, so if the first number is 90 then any following must be zero. In that case, simply set the 90 and all zero case as an alternative:

```
^(?:[+-]?(90)[°:\s]\s*(0+)[\':\s]?\s*(0+)\.(0+)[\"]?|[+-]?([0-8]?\d)[°:\s]\s*([0-5]?\d)[\':\s]?\s*([0-5]?\d)\.(\d+)[\"]?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Z0Kf6I/4

With some explanation, suitable for [Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#/x-and-/xx) or [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X) with the `x` flag:

```
^ # start of line
(?:
    [+-]?(90)[°:\s]        # 90 degrees with optional unit or separator
    \s*
    (0+)[\':\s]?           # 0 minutes with optional unit or separator
    \s*
    (0+)\.(0+)[\"]?        # 0.0 seconds with optional unit
| # OR
    [+-]?([0-8]?\d)[°:\s]  # 0-89 degrees with optional unit or separator
    \s*
    ([0-5]?\d)[\':\s]?     # 0-59 minutes with optional unit or separator
    \s*
    ([0-5]?\d)\.(\d+)[\"]? # 0-59 seconds with optional unit
)
```

But as I said in comments, this is better accomplished with whatever language you're using. Split it on the possible separators and then do whatever checks your logic dictates. It is easier to understand and maintain code than regular expressions.